# Serverless deploy stopped working suddenly

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, serverless, serverless-framework

[image]

When I'm trying to deploy nothing is happening, I'm not getting any error, last week it was working.Any ideas? Thank you !

Comment: Your question does not have enough information for us to be able to assist you. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)